# image manipulation using quartz2d

Tags: ios

```
CGSize cgs = CGSizeMake(250.0, 300.0);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(cgs);    
    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(0,0,cgs.width,cgs.height);
    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BMW.jpg"]; 

    [myImage drawInRect:rectangle];    
    [myImage release];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0); 
    CGContextStrokeRect(context, rectangle);

    UIImage *testImg =  UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [testImg drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(35, 10)];
```

i want to give gap between image and rectangle borders in which image is drawn, like 5 on left 5 on top and 5 on right but around 30 on bottom because its the space for text that user will write and user can also select that he/she want text on top so in that case top gap will be 30 and bottom gap will be 5. Here is the code it is inside subclass of uiview in drawrect method.

using this code border and image are tightly bound together, i am unable to give gap between border and image. Any idea how can i do that?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First of all,** you have a serious bug.  This line is **wrong**:

```
[myImage release];
```

You don't own `myImage`, so you should **not** release it.  You need to read “Memory-Management Rules” in [*Cocoa Core Competencies*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html).  Or you should turn on ARC (automatic reference counting), and then the compiler will take care of releasing things for you.  Since ARC is supported since iOS 4.0, you should almost certainly be using it if you're developing a new app.

Regarding your image drawing, you just need to modify the rectangle in which you're drawing the image.  For example, you can leave a 5 pixel border on top, left, and right, and a 30 point border on the bottom like this:

```
CGRect imageRect = CGRectInset(rectangle, 5, 5);  // move 5 points in on all sides
imageRect.size.height -= 25;  // make it another 25 points shorter
[myImage drawInRect:imageRect];
```

If you want the 30 point border on top, you also need to modify `imageRect.origin.y`.

Comment: thanks a lot for the replay and pointing out the bug... i modified the code and its working but image is going out of the border and spreading into the left top right bottom gap please check the screenshot i am attaching it. I want gap inside border not outside the border.

Comment: I said you should modify the rectangle that you use to draw the *image*.  I didn't say you should modify the rectangle that you use to draw the *border*.  Why do you think I created a new variable named `imageRect`?

Comment: I did use the wrong variable in `drawInRect:`.  I have fixed that.